# How should this post be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I came across this question: [To find the missing digits in pythonic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58072061/to-find-the-missing-digits-in-pythonic-way)

It's very clearly off topic.

The flagging dialogue has a couple options

- **duplicate** of...
- **off topic** because...
- **unclear** what you're asking
- too broad
- **primarily opinion based**.

It isn't a duplicate, nor is what's being asked unclear. `too broad` *could* apply, but it doesn't seem like the best option. `primarily opinion based` does seem like a possibility, but "pythonic" is a term viewed very similarly by most people.

The `off topic because...` dialogue has a few options as well, none of which perfectly apply. With editing, it would work well on the code review site (maybe?), but that's not an option in the `belongs on another site` dialogue.

So how should I flag this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having trouble actually applying a flag to a question, that's *usually* a good indication that the question *isn't* something you should flag.

In this instance, the question itself - in its terseness - contains just enough information to work towards an answer, including code and a problem statement.  Closing it would be inappropriate.

If nothing else, the question title *could* be edited to remove any suggestion of this question looking for an opinionated answer.

Comment: In my experience "pythonic" is sort of a trigger word for a vague/can't be applied elsewhere question. Seeing as it's downvoted to -3, at least 3 people agree with me. Can you elaborate a little more? Thanks.

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises - if that's the *only* issue you can find with the post, then it's salvageable, and can be edited out.

Comment: The post had been closed **unclear** (which I'd consider not a wrong descision) but has now been edited with expected output examples.